# How do I set the default linestyle for plots in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, coding-style, plot, linestyle

I have an array of data that I would like to plot

```
temp=0.5*rand(500,10);
[~,offset]=meshgrid(1:500,1:10);
figure(101)
plot(temp+offset')
```

How can I set the line style to automatically change to the next style once the line colours have been through one cycle?

For this example I would like the 8-10th lines to have a different line style.  I can do it manually but I'd like Matlab to do it for me if I can set a default option somewhere.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your first inclination might be to just change the [`'LineStyleOrder'` property](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/axes_props.html#LineStyleOrder) of the axes before plotting your data. Unfortunately, high-level plotting functions like [PLOT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/plot.html) will reset the [`'LineStyleOrder'` property](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/axes_props.html#LineStyleOrder) of the axes to it's default value `'-'`before plotting. One solution is to [change the default value](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_plots/f7-21465.html) used by all axes objects at the [root level](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/rootobject.html). For example:

```
set(0,'DefaultAxesLineStyleOrder',{'-',':'});
```

Will first use a solid line, then a dotted line, and then repeat again if necessary for each plot. Note that you could also use a custom [`'ColorOrder'` property](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/axes_props.html#ColorOrder) with high-level plotting functions by changing the default value at the root as well. The following example will change it so [PLOT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/plot.html) cycles between only red, green, and blue:

```
set(0,'DefaultAxesColorOrder',[1 0 0; 0 1 0; 0 0 1]);
```

Instead of worrying about different line styles, another solution to your problem would be to set the default color order to have more than just 7 colors.

Once default property values on the root are set, they will stay that way until MATLAB is closed. When reopened, the default property values will be set back to their factory-defined values. Commands like [CLEAR](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/clear.html) won't set default properties back to their factory-defined values. Instead, you should set the default property value to `'remove'` to undo user-defined values, like so:

```
set(0,'DefaultAxesLineStyleOrder','remove');  %# Sets the default back to '-'
```

As another alternative to changing the default properties used by *all* axes objects, if you change the [`NextPlot` property](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/axes_props.html#NextPlot) of an individual axes to anything *except* `'replace'` you can then change the [`'LineStyleOrder'`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/axes_props.html#LineStyleOrder) or [`'ColorOrder'`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/axes_props.html#ColorOrder) properties to whatever you want and [PLOT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/plot.html) will not reset them to their defaults. For example, this should do what you want as well:

```
set(gca,'NextPlot','add','LineStyleOrder',{'-',':'});
plot(temp+offset');
```

Comment: So if the OP wants the style to cycle `'r-','g-','b-','r:','g:','b:'`, they could put `'ColorOrder'` to `[1 0 0; 0 1 0; 0 0 1]` and LineStyleOrder to `{'-','-','-',':',':',':'}`, right?

Comment: @Jonas: Actually, they would only need to set LineStyleOrder to `{'-',':'}`, since PLOT will first cycle through all the colors once with the first line style, then again with the second line style. In other words, colors cycle in an inner loop, line style in an outer loop.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, just a quick question, do the defaults get reset if I call  clear all

Comment: @mor22: Short answer: no. For more detail, I updated my answer to address how you can reset default property values to their factory-defined settings.

Comment: I tried removing the added colors as you explain in your answer. However, odd colors appear instead of the default ones when you open MATLAB. To solve this I save the original style: `OC = get(0,'DefaultAxesColorOrder');` and then restore it later with `set(0,'DefaultAxesColorOrder',OC);`. I don't know why the `remove` didn't work for me.