# MATLAB: set line's color and style order to be applied in parallel

Tags: matlab, colors, plot, line, linestyle

When you set `DefaultAxesColorOrder` and `DefaultAxesLineStyleOrder` MATLAB will first cycle through all colors with the first style, then again through all colors with the second style and so on.

See this [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_plots/bqsxy_a-1.html) or [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258341/how-do-i-set-the-default-linestyle-for-plots-in-matlab).

What I would like to do is to set color order and style order to be applied independently.

For example, if I set `DefaultAxesColorOrder` to `[1 0 0; 0 1 0; 0 0 1]` and `DefaultAxesLineStyleOrder` to `'-|--|:'`, the lines will be `'r-'`,`'g-'`,`'b-'`,`'r--'`,`'g--'`,`'b--'`,`'r:'`,`'g:'`,`'b:'`. I want lines to be `'r-'`,`'g--'`,`'b:'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see a way to do this directly out of the box. The straightforward way is to set the color/style manually for each line.

Here is a more automated solution. Let's start with an example taken from the documentation:

```
%# defaults are set sometime before
set(0, 'DefaultAxesColorOrder',[1 0 0;0 1 0;0 0 1], ...
      'DefaultAxesLineStyleOrder','-|--|:')

%# do plotting as usual
t = 0:pi/20:2*pi;
a = zeros(length(t),9);
for i = 1:9
    a(:,i) = sin(t-i/5)';
end
h = plot(t,a);
```

As you explained in your question, the default behavior is to cycle through the colors first, then the line styles. If you want to apply them independently, try the following:

```
c = num2cell(get(0,'DefaultAxesColorOrder'),2);
l = cellstr(get(0,'DefaultAxesLineStyleOrder'));
set(h, {'Color'}, c(rem((1:numel(h))-1,numel(c))+1), ...
    {'LineStyle'}, l(rem((1:numel(h))-1,numel(l))+1))
```

You can maybe wrap that in a function for convenient access (you still have to pass the handles to the lines graphic objects):

```
function applyColorLineStyleIndependently(h)
    %# ...
end
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's great! I never used cell arrays in `set`.

Answer (score 1):

Amro's approach works well. Just as a note, you don't have to set the defaults to do this. You can do something like this

```
col = mycolors(); % defines RGB colors scaled to [0,1]

i = 1;
c(:,i) = col.royal_blue; i = i+1;
c(:,i) = col.crimson; i = i+1;
c(:,i) = col.medium_sea_green; i = i+1;
c(:,i) = col.coral; i = i+1;
c(:,i) = col.dark_magenta; i = i+1;

colord = num2cell(c',2);
lineord = {'-' '--' '-.'}'; 

set(h,{'Color'}, colord(rem((1:numel(h))-1,numel(colord))+1), ...
      {'LineStyle'}, lineord(rem((1:numel(h))-1,numel(lineord))+1))
set(h,'LineWidth',2)
```

Edit: the mycolors() function is home made. I define

```
colors.maroon = [128,0,0];
colors.dark_red = [139,0,0];
colors.brown = [165,42,42];
...
```

(the color names are from this http://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.htm). Then I scale them to [0,1] via

```
c = fieldnames(colors);
for i = 1:numel(c)
    colors.(c{i}) = colors.(c{i})/255;
end
```

Comment: Thanks. What is mycolors function? I didn't find it neither in MATLAB or FileExchange. Is it your own code?